# Loading mutiple 'Gets' into an array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I am pulling a list of categories from my Big Commerce site into a PHP script, but the controls at Big Commerce limit the number of categories that you can load at any given time to 250 (I have almost 1,000).

The current command is

```
$categories = get("categories?page=$index&limit=250");
```

as the `$index` increases from page 1 to 2 and so on, should this be adding the next page into the array `$categories`, or would it replace the current array?

Comment: is this line you shown here resides in a loop ? can you show more code ?

Comment: have you tried changing the limit param? `get("categories?page=$index&limit=1000");`

Comment: I did try raising the limit.  The limit is set on their side, and going over 250 results in a null response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looping like so:

```
$categories = array();
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) // this will give you 4*250 = 1000 categories
    $categories = array_merge($categories, get("categories?page=$i&limit=250"));
```

I assume the returned array has numerical indexes, so according to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.

Answer (score 0):

Yotam's solution was almost perfect.  I just needed to assign each get to an array first, and double check for an empty array.  Otherwise, great!

```
    $categories = array();
$TmpCat = array();
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){ // this will give you 4*250 = 1000 categories
    $TmpCat = get("categories?page=$i&limit=250");
    If($TmpCat != ""){
    $categories = array_merge($categories, $TmpCat);
    }
    }
```